# Mobile Number Locator API

Tags: api, mobile

I have search so many times in google but not get the result. Actually i am searching a Free API for mobile number locator for India.

When i pass the mobile number in the API, it should return the "Service Provider" & "Circle".

I am developing a application on it but not get the API. Please help me.

Comment: There's an API known as Meshape and loc-aid's. But they are not free.

Comment: @TheOnlyAnil I want Free API, There are so many application which provide this kind of facility but i don't know, where they get the Response.

Answer (score 2):

Bad luck their are no free service available to locate mobile number.

But their is an way by which you can find mobile number provider and their circle or state.

You can modify [this script](https://github.com/rahulchordiya/Indian-mobile-circle) according to your platform language.

Answer (score 1):

There can be multiple answers to this question

1. You can Go to Wikipedia India mobile number database (search it) and grab the data and make your own database from it. Note: The series listed are a bit Old.
2. You can make a script using php curl or python and make a **scraper** from mobile number info sites.
3. You can search for mashape.com can find various free APIs for indian mobile numbers
4. If you want checking Ported Mobile numbers or numbers who are using Mobile number portability, you can use Datayuge.in operator checking API.

Answer (score 0):

There is a ready to use free API for looking up indian mobile number . This API takes mobile number and returns operator name and circle ( State ) of the mobile number . Essentially it lookup a DB based on first four digits of number ( [Read more on Wikipedia  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_telephone_numbering_in_India ) . Please note this may not be accurate if a mobile subscriber has changed state and kept same number using mobile number portability.

Source : [https://market.mashape.com/nviror/mobile-number-tracker-india]

You have to create an account on mashape & get the credentials to call API. 
Send request in following format to API URL

```
// These code snippets use an open-source library. http://unirest.io/net
Task<HttpResponse<MyClass>> response = Unirest.post("https://mobileinfo.p.mashape.com/")
.header("X-Mashape-Key", "ZGpCbd8tLpmshmlkk1sOVgRuXdHmp1yJ7s3jsnT7z6fQpJ2Sts")
.header("Content-Type", "application/json")
.header("Accept", "application/json")
.body("{\"mobile\":9999999999}")
.asJson();
```

You will get a return response as

```
   {
  "mobile": 9999999999,
  "serie": 9999,
  "operator": {
    "code": "VF",
    "name": "Vodafone",
    "company": "Vodafone India Ltd"
  },
  "circle": {
    "code": "DL",
    "name": "Delhi Metro Telecom Circle (includes NCR, Faridabad, Ghaziabad, Gurgaon and Noida)"
  }
}
```